# Inconsistent behavior in boto3 method generate_presigned_url(), SignatureDoesNotMatch sometimes

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, boto3

I'm currently in quite a pickle and I'm unsure how to proceed.

I am currently building out a fullstack messaging platform where users can send each other messages, with attachments. It's very similar to a toned-down email system.

I want the user uploaded files to be hosted on S3. This S3 bucket will (eventually) have an access control list but it is currently public. As a result, I am attempting to implement attachment downloads via a presigned URL that I render clientside. The user clicks the URL, gets taken to AWS, and a download of the file automatically commences. At least, this should be the behavior.

When I upload the files (I do it in batches of 4 files, all different filetypes), I print the presigned URLs that I generate, with a default expiration time of 1 hour.

The thing is, is that usually these URLs work! I click them and the file downloads. However, once in a while I will get an SignatureDoesNotMatch error, rarely for all 4 files in the batch but maybe one or two. All the other posts on SO regarding this error seem to be caused by improperly pasted AWS Access Credentials, so I made sure to check these. I'm not sure what the issue is and would like to see if anyone else has had this issue.

Here is the code for my methods:

```
class AttachmentTest(APIView):
    '''
    POST:
    Creates an Attachment Model per attachment sent
    '''

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.FILES)
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        folder_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
        for file in request.FILES:
            object_key = 'mail_attachments/' + request.user.username + '/' + folder_name + '/' + request.FILES[file].name
            s3.Bucket('MY_BUCKET_NAME').put_object(Key=object_key, Body=request.FILES[file], ContentType=request.FILES[file].content_type)
            print(create_presigned_url('MY_BUCKET_NAME', object_key))
        return Response("attachment logged")
```

Above is the API endpoint I post the files to, via Postman.

Here is the `create_presigned_url()` method, copied straight from AWS documentation:

```
def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=3600):
    """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
    :return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
    """

    # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': object_name},
                                                    ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL
    return response
```

Here's a sample presigned url:
`https://<MY_BUCKET_NAME>.s3.amazonaws.com/mail_attachments/isaac/775054eb-a83e-49e1-974d-bbf3f88e32ba/%F0%9F%98%80?AWSAccessKeyId=<MY_ACCESS_KEY>&Signature=SFodxvdJbVvClINL7M%2BZPym273Y%3D&Expires=1561585952`

Please let me know if you've encountered this issue. I'm not sure if it's a bug on Amazon's side (I'm assuming I'm 100x more likely to cause an error than the AWS team, haha.) I have an idea that it could be due to the way that the URL is encoded, but I'm not totally sure. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Examine several signed URLs.  One possible pattern is that the ones that don't work are the ones that include the substring `%2B` in the `Signature`.  Less likely, the problem is when the signature contains the substring `%2F`.  Or maybe I'm on the wrong path, but please check whether you can confirm this.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You're right, the URL's that do not work all contain %2B. I'm also finding that when I right click the link from my terminal, the URL does not work. However when I simply copy/paste the URL, it does work. Upon comparing the nonworking URL and working URL, I'm finding that the SignatureDoesNotMatch error is raised when the '%2B' string is converted to a '+' (which is done when I right click), and when I copy/paste and the '%2B' string is preserved the URL works. Thanks for the guidance, if you could explain the issue deeper I'm all ears but regardless, I appreciate the advice.